# App Domain: is not a valid domain

Tags: facebook, dns

any idea why  get this error when I insert my site name in App Domain box ,when ntrying to setup app ?   I've tried inserting other domains and I get rhe same error message.

Error

App Domain: http://wordpressblogplugins.com/  is not a valid domain.

Comment: try only "wordpressblogplugins.com"

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem. the error log is sketchy. this is the solution:

```
1st goto WEBSITE (below SELECT HOW YOUR APP CONNECTS...) and click
2nd in the text area, fill in your website           http://www.yourdomain.info
3rd go back to APP DOMAIN (BASIC INFO) and type      yourdomain.info
```

This absolutely works but I didn't quite understand the instructions, so I'm going to restate them for other neophytes like myself.

1. From the Facebook development page "Apps-YourAppName", click on Basic in the LEFT Nav.
2. There are 3 sections on this page: Basic Info, Cloud Services, and "Select how your app integrates with Facebook"
3. In the Select how your app integrates with Facebook section, select "Website"
4. Enter your fully qualified domain name in the Site URL dialog box. Example: http://www.mydomain.com OR http://mydomain.com (my site does not include the www so I didn't add it).
5. At the bottom of the page click the "Save Changes" button. You may receive a notice that it may take several minutes to blah blah blah....but you can continue with the next steps immediately.
6. Now, in the Basic Information section at the top of this screen, you can now add your App Domain. This should be formatted as mydomain.com. Do not add "http://" and do not add "/" at the end of the domain name.
7. NOTE: My site does not use the www, so I cannot confirm that it's required in Step #6. Try it both ways if you're unsure.
8. At the bottom of the page click the "Save Changes" button. You may receive a notice that it may take several minutes to blah blah blah....but you can continue with the next steps immediately.
9. At this point the error was NOT displayed as it was before.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cursed FB for having made the setting so bad. Yes, your solution worked at the end for me!

Comment: "There was a problem saving your changes Please try again later" is the error that is occurring now.. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that the UI(on developers.facebook.com) is already tweaked. Now, all we have to do is just push [+Add Platform] and input [Site URL] first. It's still weird process, though. Why do we have to fill the form from bottom?

Answer (score 2):

You should not place URL `scheme` to the "App Domain" field (it's not a part of [domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name#Domain_name_syntax)), just the domain name like **wordpressblogplugins.com**

Comment: still it refusing